# Old remote alias still visible in git logs and gitk, how to delete?

Tags: git, git-remote

I recently renamed a remote to a new alias and the old alias (and all its commits up until the point of renaming) is still visible in the logs and consequently gitk. Running

```
$ git remote show old-alias
```

obviously returns:

```
fatal: 'old-alias' does not appear to be a git repository
```

This is pretty annoying. How do I cleanly remove these references? Is it OK if I manually delete the

```
.git/logs/refs/remotes/old-alias/
.git/refs/remotes/old-alias/
```

directories?

**Edit:**

Here is the `git remote -v` output:

```
origin  git@github.com:my-user/our-repo (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:my-user/our-repo (push)
upstream        git@github.com:upstream-user/our-repo (fetch)
upstream        git@github.com:upstream-user/our-repo (push)
```

Here is the `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` output:

```
* 692d53f (HEAD, origin/somebranch, somebranch) Commit message                                                                                                                                 
* 9a4e794 Commit message                                                                                                                                                     
* 419376b Commit message
* 9a945bd (origin/someotherbranch, someotherbranch) Commit message
* 9a0fe3b Commit message
* 021d553 Commit message
* fa60dba Commit message
* 2d52d72 Commit message
* c59307f Commit message
* b89ae1c Commit message
* 063030c Commit message
* 97b8c77 Commit message
* ec65002 Commit message
* 38d7bb8 Commit message
* 36856fc Commit message
* 13b5065 Commit message
*   66e7dae (upstream/master, origin/master, old-alias/master, master) Commit message
|\  
| * caf7e86 Commit message
| * a0c5abe Commit message
| * 9d1a735 Commit message
| * 4e7770d Commit message
| * cd3dd89 Commit message
* |   3037432 Merge pull request message
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 12b4a01 Commit message
| * be41159 Commit message
|/  
* 8210859 Commit message
* 6b2090e Commit message
* 4b069f3 Commit message
*   1ef939c Merge pull request message
|\  
| * fc559bb Commit message
|/  
* 6fab424 Commit message
* ce10b38 Commit message
* 345128e Commit message
```

`old-alias` was changed to `origin` around commit `2d52d72` via `git remote rename old-alias origin`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches

Comment: I don't see how that would help my case in any way, it is related to remote branches. My problem is a whole residual remote.

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to just go deleting files under `.git` unless you ***really*** know what you're doing. What is the output of `git remote -v`? What do you mean that the old alias still show up in the logs? Can we see? What is the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`?

Comment: I added the information you requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question here has a similar issue: [Why is old name of git remote sill in .git/refs/remotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426231/why-is-old-name-of-git-remote-sill-in-git-refs-remotes?rq=1). Following the advice there, I deleted the

```
.git/logs/refs/remotes/old-alias/
.git/refs/remotes/old-alias/
```

directories manually. There are residual logs in `.git/logs/HEAD` and `.git/logs/refs/heads/someotherbranch`:

```
./logs/HEAD:14:6d8019... Ayberk Özgür <ayberk.ozgur@email.com> 1394819391 +0100   pull old-alias someotherbranch: Fast-forward
./logs/refs/heads/android:13:6d8019... Ayberk Özgür <ayberk.ozgur@email.com> 1394819391 +0100     pull old-alias someotherbranch: Fast-forward
```

I don't exactly know if those are the only traces left of `old-alias` or whether they may be harmful. However, I haven't encountered any issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, what I ended up with:

```
export REMOTE_NAME="old-alias" # insert your remote name
for branch in $(git branch -a | grep -o "${REMOTE_NAME}/.*") ; do
    git branch -r -d $branch
done
```

I had a very similar issue, although even after recklessly deleting content from my .git directory - probably don't do that! - I still had the remote references.

For me, the trick was to use the `-r` option to deleting a git branch: `git branch -r -d` as suggested by bitoiu (in the referenced answer).

I used this in conjunction with `git br -a` because I had ~20 orphaned remote branches and I wanted to loop over them to delete them all.

I expect since readers have git that grep has the `-o` option to only return the matched substring.  If not, prune the leading `remotes/` with your tool of choice, such as `| sed -e 's/^remotes.//'`, which I use on QNX (although I don't have git on QNX).

Finally, if you prefer one liners, it's worth learning the sh/bash for loop one-line syntax: `for branch in $(git branch -a | grep -o "old-alias/.*") ; do git branch -r -d $branch ; done`